# Apple Push Notifications Configuration

Tags: push-notification, ios-provisioning

I am getting ready to submit an app to the Apple App Store.   My App ID does not have a wildcard and the provisioning portal has a yellow light with "Configurable" for Push Notification. In the future I plan on using push notifications.  Do I need to configure my app ID for push notifications now or can I do it on a future release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable the push notifications in the future release and it's better after you enable the push notifications recreate a new provision profile which contain the updated apple ID.

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same problem. I had it token care of!

You need to add iOS push certificate！

https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/certificate/certificateCreate.action

Apple Push Notification service SSL (Sandbox & Production).
[image]